# Using Capistrano, how can I see a list of releases and then rollback to one of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Using Capistrano, how can I see a list of releases and then rollback to one of them?

This is a rails app, running on phusion with nginx.

Answer (score 1):

To see what versions have been previously released - I use the Capistrano shell

```
$ cap shell
# Show the release directory - it might be a long list
cap> ls  /mnt/html/deployed/releases/
 ** [out :: hostname.example.com] 20110521130031

# which revisions are current now
cap> cat  /mnt/html/deployed/current/REVISION
 ** [out :: hostname.example.com] 5201
```

There's no way to roll back to a specific version (that isn't the previous one). You can release that older one though.

> If you want to push a tag, you have to
>   change the :repository URL (since
>   Subversion doesn't really support
>   tags--you actually push from a
>   different path in the repository
>   instead). If you want to push a
>   specific revision number from the
>   current repository, you  just set the
>   :revision variable.  You can set
>   either of these from the command-line:
>   *from:* http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/msg/10cc8ac9997d5e2a

```
cap -s repository=http://blah.blah.blah deploy
cap -s revision=123 deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cap deploy:rollback -s previous_release=/path/to/release/on/server
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11139185/620780 or look at capistrano source at [github](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L358)