# With Capistrano, how to rollback to a specific release?

Tags: capistrano

With Capistrano, how to rollback to a specific release?

My server's folder has a /release folder, how can I rollback to a specific one?

Is it possible for me to get a list of releases on my computer locally?

I'm using GIT and this didn't work:

```
cap deploy -s revision:HASH
```

Answer (score 49):

**Update**
The answer was written in the times of capistrano version 2. With the current capistrano version 3 you can achieve the same by using

```
cap production deploy:rollback ROLLBACK_RELEASE=2010123
```

Please refer to the [Capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks) for further details.

Thanks to @codenoob for pointing this out!

---

**Old version**

The following should work:

```
cap deploy:rollback -s previous_release=/path/to/release/on/server
```

Example:

Lets say you have deployed your app to `/srv/some_app` and you have the following releases/directory structure:

```
|- srv
   |- some_app
      |- shared
      |- current -> /srv/some_app/releases/2012123
      |- releases
         |- 2010123
         |- 2011123
         |- 2012123
```

If you now want to go back from the current (*2012123*) release to the *2010123* one, you would use

```
cap deploy:rollback -s previous_release=/srv/some_app/releases/2010123
```

Comment: I think perhaps in the newer version it's: cap staging deploy:rollback ROLLBACK_RELEASE=20160614133327:  http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks/#

Answer (score 4):

Another option is

```
$ cap deploy:rollback ROLLBACK_RELEASE=20160614133327
```

from http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/rollbacks/#

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano names the release directories by date/time.

From the capistrano shell, you can connect to all the machines you are deploying to, and examine them from there:

```
$ cap shell
# Show them - it might be a long list
cap> ls  /mnt/html/deployed/releases/
 ** [out :: hostname.example.com] 20110521130031
# how many releases on each machine?
cap> ls  /mnt/html/deployed/releases/ |wc -l
```