# capistrano rollback to an old version?

Tags: capistrano

```
cap deploy:rollback
```

I know this rolls back to the last revision. How can can I rollback to an older revision?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359749/with-capistrano-how-to-rollback-to-a-specific-release) shows you how to go to a specific version.

Answer (score 6):

By executing `cap deploy:rollback`, you rollback to the previous release.

If you keep executing `cap deploy:rollback`, you will reach the release version you need.

It is not the perfect solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

To rollback to a specific release

```
cap deploy:rollback -s previous_release=/path/to/desired_release
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you can't rollback to a specific older revision, but you can deploy to a specific branch, revision or tag, etc.

For git:

```
cap -s branch=my_branch deploy
cap -s tag=my_tag deploy
```

For svn:

```
cap -s repository=http://blah.blah.blah deploy 
cap -s revision=123 deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

`cap deploy:rollback:code` will roll you back to the previously deployed version